# RenderBox was not laid out - Particular Case with Dynamic children

Tags: flutter, dart, flutter-layout

I have been struggling with this for a few hours and I do not seem to find the answer.

Here my code:

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:url_launcher/url_launcher.dart';

class Body extends StatefulWidget {
  final List jsondata;
  const Body({Key key, this.jsondata}) : super(key: key);
  @override
  State<StatefulWidget> createState() => new _State();
}

class _State extends State<Body> {
  // Create a global key that uniquely identifies the Form widget
  // and allows validation of the form.

  List<Widget> _buildList(List jsondata) {
    var list = new List<Widget>();
    var rootList = new List<Widget>();

    for (var i = 0; i < jsondata.length; i++) {
      list.add(Padding(
        padding: const EdgeInsets.all(8),
        child: Align(
          child: ListView(
            children: <Widget>[
              GestureDetector(
                onTap: () async {
                  if (await canLaunch(jsondata[i]["url"])) {
                    launch(jsondata[i]["url"]);
                  } else {
                    throw 'Could not launch ' + jsondata[i]["url"].toString();
                  }
                },
                child: Row(
                  children: <Widget>[
                    Text(jsondata[i]["feed"]),
                    Container(
                      decoration: BoxDecoration(
                        image: DecorationImage(
                          image: AssetImage(
                              'lib\Screens\News\components\background.dart'),
                          fit: BoxFit.fitWidth,
                          alignment: Alignment.topCenter,
                        ),
                      ),
                    ),
                  ],
                ),
              )
            ],
          ),
        ),
      ));
    }

    rootList.add(IntrinsicHeight(
      child: Row(
        children: <Widget>[
          Expanded(flex: 1, child: Column(children: list)),
        ],
      ),
    ));
    return rootList;
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
        body: Container(
      child: ListView.builder(
          itemCount: widget.jsondata.length,
          itemBuilder: (context, index) {
            return Card(
              child: Padding(
                padding: const EdgeInsets.all(8),
                child: ExpansionTile(
                  title: Text(widget.jsondata[index]["categoryName"]),
                  children: _buildList(widget.jsondata[index]["subCategories"]),
                ),
              ),
            );
          }),
    ));
  }
}
```

The error I am facing is:

```
    ════════ Exception caught by rendering library ═════════════════════════════════
    RenderBox was not laid out: RenderIntrinsicHeight#44af1 relayoutBoundary=up20 NEEDS-PAINT NEEDS-COMPOSITING-BITS-UPDATE
    'package:flutter/src/rendering/box.dart':
    Failed assertion: line 1702 pos 12: 'hasSize'
The relevant error-causing widget was
ExpansionTile
```

The page is intended to show expandable lists dynamically. I know they are being filled correctly based on my debugging; however, when I click on a list to expand it, it throws the error. Your help is highly appreciated.
P.S: I know that the size is the issue, but I can't seem to correct it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found this out eventually and wanted to post the answer:

```
  List<Widget> _buildList(List jsondata) {
    var list = new List<Widget>();
    var rootList = new List<Widget>();

    for (var i = 0; i < jsondata.length; i++) {
      list.add(Padding(
          padding: const EdgeInsets.all(4),
          child: Align(
              child: RichText(
            text: TextSpan(children: [
              TextSpan(
                  style: new TextStyle(color: Colors.black),
                  text: jsondata[i]["feed"]),
              TextSpan(
                  style: new TextStyle(color: Colors.blue),
                  text: ". Link",
                  recognizer: TapGestureRecognizer()
                    ..onTap = () async {
                      var url = jsondata[i]["url"];
                      if (await canLaunch(url)) {
                        await launch(url);
                      } else {
                        throw 'Could not launch $url';
                      }
                    }),
            ]),
          ))));
    }
    rootList.add(IntrinsicHeight(
      child: Column(
        children: <Widget>[
          Expanded(
              flex: 2,
              child: Column(
                children: list,
              ))
        ],
      ),
    ));
    return rootList;
  }
```

Answer (score 0):

Because the column is trying to expand in the vertical axis, that’s why you need to constrain the height of ListView.

#### 1- Use `Expanded` Widget

Use Expanded if you want to allow ListView to take up the entire left space in Column.

```
Column(
  children: <Widget>[
    Expanded(
      child: ListView(...),
    )
  ],
)
```

#### 2- User `Flexible` Widget

Use Flexible if you want to allow ListView to take up the entire left space in Column.

```
Column(
  children: <Widget>[
    Flexible(
      child: ListView(...),
    )
  ],
)
```

#### 3- Wrap your `ListView` in an `Expanded` widget

Wrap your ListView in an Expanded widget

```
 Expanded(
     child:MyListView(),
 )
```

Comment: Thank you for the answer; however, I have already tried those with no luck. You can try it on my code as well